# set permissions using batch file after taking user input

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want my batch file to take input from the user and give "Full Access" permissions to a specific folder(the path will be hard coded) to the set of users, entered by the user. The user enters a comma seperated list of user names in the form(domain\username). Please help me!!!!!!!!!! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows XP you could use the following command

```
cacls C:\GNUPG /T /E /G everyone:F
```

If username is passed as first parameter to the batch file use the following command

```
cacls C:\GNUPG /T /E /G %1:F
```

In the above parameter "C:\GNUPG" is the path name

Comment: thanks abraham but the user list is taken using set /p users. As u might have guessed users is a variable and I plan to parse this variable to extract users based on the "," delimiter and then assign permissions

Comment: You can find information on parsing comma delimited strings using batch file in these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164895/how-do-i-get-a-for-loop-to-work-on-a-single-line-comma-delimited-string-with-spac  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112694/how-do-i-get-a-for-loop-to-work-with-a-comma-delimited-string