# Windows batch comma delimited list in for loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, delimiter

I know there are a lot of related questions on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158719/how-to-loop-through-comma-separated-string-in-batch) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112694/how-do-i-get-a-for-loop-to-work-with-a-comma-delimited-string), but for some reason I couldn't get any of those working so far.

I am trying to create a batch file to install several pieces of software in a row :

Here is my batch file

```
set packages=(7zip.install, ^ :: for compression
notepadplusplus.install, ^ :: file editor
Firefox, ^
putty, ^
mysql -Version 5.5.30, ^
postgresql)

for %%i in %packages% do ( 
::echo %%i
cinst %%i
)
```

Everything works fine but for the mysql part. The space is actually taken as a delimiter, which means that I get

```
E:\>(echo 7zip.install )
7zip.install

E:\>(echo notepadplusplus.install )
notepadplusplus.install

E:\>(echo Firefox )
Firefox

E:\>(echo putty )
putty

E:\>(echo mysql )
mysql

E:\>(echo -Version )
-Version

E:\>(echo 5.5.30 )
5.5.30

E:\>(echo postgresql )
postgresql
```

What I would like to end up with is

```
E:\>(echo mysql -Version 5.5.30 )
 mysql -Version 5.5.30
```

The trick is that I want to keep my list on top of the script with one element per line, and have the possibility to insert a comment to be clear about what happens.

Is there any way to do this?

I am way more used to linux bash, and I must say I am a bit lost with the windows notations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal

for %%i in (
    "7zip.install"
    "notepadplusplus.install"
    "Firefox"
    "putty"
    "mysql -Version 5.5.30"
    "postgresql"
        ) do (
    echo %%i
    cinst "%%~i"
)
```

Comment: Thanks it does work that way. In order to make it perfect, do you know if there is a way to be able to insert comment too ? I tried "7zip.install :: comment" but it doesn't really like it :s

Comment: No, there can't be a comment inside the parentheses `()`, also `REM` doesn'n work, there is all interpreted as a valid string. Put your comment in the line before  `for %%i in (`.

Comment: You can use _percent comments_ like `"7zip.install" %= one comment%`. This is effectivly a variable expansion for an undefined variable

Comment: @jeb thank you - I doesn't like this, so I had forgotten it :)

Answer (score 2):

Although somewhat verbose, this method allows you to insert comments in each line:

```
set "packages=           7zip.install"                  // for compression
set "packages=%packages% notepadplusplus.install"       // file editor
set "packages=%packages% Firefox"
set "packages=%packages% putty"
set "packages=%packages% "mysql -Version 5.5.30""       // use nested quotes here
set "packages=%packages% postgresql"

for %%i in (%packages%) do (
   echo %%~i
   REM cinst "%%~i"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for /F "tokens=*" %%i in %packages%` ?

just example for mysql :

```
C:\temp>for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=," %i in ("%packages%") do echo %l

C:\temp>echo mysql -Version 5.5.30
mysql -Version 5.5.30
```

but I had to rewrite your var definition:

```
set packages=7zip.install,notepadplusplus.install,putty,mysql -Version 5.5.30,postgresql
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't print anything :s.

Comment: `"mysql -Version 5.5.30"` needs double quotes.

Comment: no, with the `for /f` loop it needs double quotes for `cinst "%%~i"`, but not for the loop. This will work.